# Hartl Rails Book Chapter Snapshots

Tags: ruby-on-rails, snapshot, railstutorial.org

I'm going through [Micahel Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book), and I rushed through chapter 5 to get to chapter 6.  I made a mistake somewhere along the way, and then tried to troubleshoot the errors by editing more files, commiting the wrong changes, and now I have a mess.

Does anybody have a snapshot directory of where the book should be at the beginning of chapter 6 so I can start again from there?  I could copy/paste my way there from chapter 1, but that's what got me in trouble in chapter 5.

I suppose a way to revert to any chapter's beginning is the best answer so people with the same problem in different chapters can restart.

Comment: you should fix your mistake, it's also help you understand the code. Try ask your problem on SO. If you used GIT, you can revert the code to the earlier version before you got error.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, you should just go back and figure out what went wrong - if you did use git as suggested, then you should be able to 'rollback' to the previous commits and get your code back.
To do this:

```
git log
```

this will show you the list of commits made - You'll see something like:

```
commit 89915b4cc0810a9c9e67b3706a2850c58120cf75
Author: Tom Smith <suppressed>
Date:   Wed Aug 18 20:15:01 2010 -0300

Added a proper layout.
```

You can then revert back to a 'working' version with:

```
git reset --hard 89915b4cc0810a9c9e67b3706a2850c58120cf75
```

or

```
git rm -r .
git checkout 89915b4cc0810a9c9e67b3706a2850c58120cf75
```

You're now back at the commit that worked and can resume the tutorial with working files.